# Automatically removing Dock icons not consistent in Mountain Lion

Tags: mac, macos, dock

I know that whenever we add an icon to the dock, it gets added to `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist` file. 
So, when I wanted to remove a dock icon from a program, I removed the corresponding entry from the plist file. However, I am seeing some issues in Mountain Lion(only). Sometimes, when I delete the entry from the `com.apple.dock.plist` file and kill the dock, the dock icon is still present in the dock. I am not sure how this can be possible. I confirmed that the application is not running. Is there any other location where dock information gets stored? Has anybody else faced such issues?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you edit the plist instead of dragging the icon out of the Dock?

Comment: Why can't you just use the drag out method to remove dock icons? Is this for some sort of scripting that you need to manually edit the plist?

Comment: Yes, the process is a part of an automation script which removes the entry from the plist file to remove the dock icon. The same was working consistently till MacOS 10.7.

Comment: So the script also does not work on OS X 10.7, correct?

Comment: The script work fine on 10.7 and below systems. Problem occurs only in 10.8